# How to hide one element while showing another?

Tags: jquery, toggle, grouping, slidetoggle

I have set up an accordion styled Q&A section on my site that I'm building. When you click on a question it shows the answer. I want to tie the toggle actions together so that when one question is open and another is clicked, that the open one will close and the clicked one will open.

Here is a live example so that you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/reevine/WmAb7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an `$('.active').toggleClass('active').next().hide();` before the `$(this).toggleClass('active')..` line

You might also want to change the `open` class to `active` to maintain consistency. You can start your code with `$('div.toggler:not(.active)').hide();`

Edit:

I ended up changing a good amount, here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/capo64/WmAb7/16/

Comment: There is one small issue that I see: There is always one of the `div` open at any time. What would you add to still allow the default action of all of the "questions" to be closed at the same time?